# Sitecore Virtual User Login Experience Profile

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I need to validate user credentials from external service, therefore I'm using the `VirtualUser` authentication.

- `BuildVirtualUser`, checking for the roles to set to him, saving the user Profile and then login with that name.

I'm facing a problem, that everyday that i login, with the same credentials Sitecore creates a new user in Experience Profile.
What i need to change in my code to assure that, with virtual user login, Sitecore gets the old experience profile of the user?

I was thinking in creating the user in sitecore with same generic password. Instead of using the virtual user, and authenticate directly with sitecore. Is that correct?

Here's my code:

```cs
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(sitecoreUser, true);
string roleName = @"newRole\User";
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role demoRole = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.FromName(roleName);

if (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.Exists(roleName) && !demoRole.IsMember(user, true, false))
{
    user.Roles.Add(Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.FromName(roleName));
}

user.Profile.Name = name;
user.Profile.Email = email;
user.Profile.FullName = fullname;

user.Profile.Save();
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(user.Name);

Tracker.Initialize();
```

Answer (score 3):

Code looks fine, but you miss one important thing: to identify your user/contact.

You need to add next line of code:

```
  Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(email);
```

Please check next link to find more information about how to identify contacts:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/contacts/identifying_contacts

Comment: Thanks, i've also another question. Is that possible to know if a virtual user already exists?  To know if was already identiied to implement a rule to it.  Or to do this is better to create the user in sitecore?  
I mean, i will need to authenticate through their system and i will need to know if it's the first time or not.

Comment: After some tests, I got an error. I've inserted the code that you said after Tracker.Initialize() and I've an error "this.Interaction should not be null"